# How to store a jsonify response into string variable

Tags: python, json, flask

```
json_data2 = some_func(DB, pra1)
data = jsonify(result = json_data2)
```

I want to convert the "data" into a string variable, is there a convenient way?

Comment: Where is your `jsonify` function coming from? That's not a builtin, nor part of the `json` module. If its part of a framework, can you add an appropriate tag?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you just want to store json from the response object into string variable, or a complete response object needs to serialized into string variable. The first one is very simple with import json; json.dumps({'x': 1}). Also, what is json_data2: string, dict, list, or?

Answer (score 3):

The `Response` class has a [`get_data()`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.get_data) accessor.

```
json_data2 = some_func(DB, pra1)
data = jsonify(result = json_data2)
print data.get_data(as_text=True)
```